Law of Total Probability with Extra Conditioning Examples?
I cannot understand the logic behind the Total Law of Probability with Extra Conditioning. I am hoping to get some simple examples that explains it. The ones I have seen so far are still very confusing and some of it uses intersects instead of conditioning, which confuses me even more. Any help would be grateful.


The two expressions in your image are equivalent:  $P(A\cap B_k \mid C)=P(A \mid B_k,C)P(B_k \mid C)$

As a (not rigorous) example you can think of computing how many green areas you travel knowing you're on street $C$ where on top of that you have a partition of all green areas in $n$ distinct regions. You can compute the amount of green area you travel in each region and sum them up.
Note that $\{B_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$ must be a partition of your sample space, i.e. the union must cover the whole space, the sets are two-by-two disjoint sets and it is a non-empty collection.
If you're a bit familiar with measure theory if you have such a partition of the whole space $X$ then you can compute the measure of a set $E$ in the $\sigma$-algebra as follows:
$$\mu(E) = \mu(E\cap X) = \mu\left(E \cap \bigcup_{i}B_{i}\right) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{i}E\cap B_{i}\right) = \sum_{i}\mu(E\cap B_{i}).$$
Now, if you consider the set $E=A\cap C$ and plug it above you actually get the second equation you wrote.
